# Set variables to controller in MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER

Tags: php, zend-framework2, variable-assignment

In my callback to the EVENT_RENDER, I'm able to assign variables to the viewModel. I'd like also like to set some variables to the controller, but its not working

Example:

```
$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function(MvcEvent $e) {
        $vars = \Utils\GsInterface::getVariables();
        $e->getViewModel()->setVariables($vars);//Set ok

        $ctr = $e->getController();
        foreach ($vars as $name => $var) {
            $ctr->{$name} = $var;//Don't work
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain "not working"? Do you have an error or is on the controller class the variable not accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet money that you are receiving the error because you are trying to set variables to a `$ctr` that is not your controller, but `null`,  since probably your `$e->getController();` is returning null.

if you turn warnings on, you will receive some like  `Creating default object from empty value` or some other derived from accesing a null object.

I think that `$e->getController();` doesn't do exactly what you want. Probably you should try with `$e->getTarget();`, but not in the render event, but in the dispatch. This will help you in two ways:

- `$e->getTarget()` will give you the actual Controller object, so the error disappears.
- It has more sense if you apply some variables to the controller, before that the action has been dispatched, otherwise you won't be able to use them.

So, i would use:

```
$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, function(MvcEvent $e) {
        $vars = \Utils\GsInterface::getVariables();
        $e->getViewModel()->setVariables($vars); 
}); 

$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function(MvcEvent $e) {

        $ctr = $e->getTarget(); 
         $vars = \Utils\GsInterface::getVariables();

         foreach ($vars as $name => $var) {
            $ctr->{$name} = $var; 
         }
    });
```